# Django view with form and objects

Tags: python, django

I want to create view with form to create post and show post in the same page 
but i don't know how i can do it because when i add to view.py form i dont see my objects i mean "posts from database"

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.utils import timezone
from django.http import Http404
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views import generic
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView

from .forms import HomeForm
from .models import simplePost


class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'myapp/index.html'


    def get_queryset(self):
        return simplePost.objects.all()

class ProfileView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'myapp/profile.html'
    model_name = simplePost
    form_class = HomeForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['message'] = simplePost.objects.all() # filter this?
        return context
```

Comment: `new_item = get_object_or_404(simplePost)` likely fails if there are no `simplePost` objects, or more than one.

Comment: With new_item = get_object_or_404(simplePost) is my bad because i try repair this and i paste wrong code sorry

Comment: I think it is probably better to use a `FormView` here, since this will already reduce the view a *lot*, hence it is easier to spot mistakes in the remaining parts: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#formview

Comment: do you want to show saved simplePost object after it will be created?

Comment: Hmm yes i used FormView i see my form in template but i dont see objects i mean posts from database only when i delete all functions associated with form i see my posts

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would approach that. Use the generic class based views to eliminate some of your boilerplate code around form processing (CreateView, UpdateView, or FormView): https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#createview

Then just add to your context variable in get_context_data to have all of the Post data you want to display. You can then iterate through them in your template to display them with the posts context variable.

```
class ProfileView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'myapp/profile.html'
    model_name = Profile
    form_class = HomeForm

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['posts'] = simplePost.objects.all() # filter this?
        return context
```

Template section for displaying posts:

```
{% for post in posts %}
    {{ post.body }}
    {{ post.author }}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Again i see only form to create post but i don't see posts i will add more code up if this can help^

Comment: This single view should give you a form and a list of posts, you just have to use the context variable that contains all your posts in your template. If you want everything on the same page, only one view is needed.

Comment: I have template like this but i still dont have posts i see them when i use old method like in IndexView i mean def get_queryset(self):
        return simplePost.objects.all()